# Laravel backpack: Customize a row styling on a table?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

Currently, The Team looks something like this:

[image: 1]

```
   protected function setupListOperation()
    {
    ...
    $this->crud->addColumn([
    'name' => 'name',
    'label' => "Name", 
    'type' => 'name',

    'wrapper'   => [
        'style' => function ($crud, $column, $entry, $related_key) {
            return ("color:$entry->secondary_color ;background-color:$entry->primary_color;);
        },
    ],

]);
...
    }
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to set that background colour to the whole row instead of just the Name.

It should be looking like this instead:
[image]

I've had a glance at backpack documentation to change a row CSS via wrapper() method, something like $this->crud->ColumnCSS() or something similar, but I'm not able to find anything close to it.

Can I achieve this? Getting the current row variables and attaching it to the CSS of its row?

Comment: What does the rendered HTML for the table rows look like?

Comment: @miken32 its the first picture.

Comment: @NishDekardo did you manage to get this done? Trying to figure out the same thing.